# StageWebView, iOS, local files

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, air

I'm building a mobile app for IOS using Flash Builder, Flex 4.6 and AIR 3.5.  I'm investigating using StageWebView to render some HTML5 content.

What I want to do is to build the content into the app, as opposed to putting it on a server.  It's relatively static.  But I read (and confirmed) that in-app files can't be used directly by StageWebView.  But following a suggestion, I'm have the app copy the content to a temp folder, then create a file:// URL for StageWebView, which seems to work:

```
//  create the view
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

//  copy the HTML5 content to a temp directory
var src:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("myFolder");
var temp:File = File.createTempDirectory().resolvePath("myFolder");
copyFolderContentsToAnotherFolder(src,temp);

//  what's the URL
var newPath:String = "file://" + temp.nativePath + "/index.html";

//  load it
webView.loadURL(newPath);
```

Is this a bad idea?  Will temporary files pile up in my device with no way to delete them?

I also thought of having the app implement an minimal HTTP server by listening on a port and supplying the data for requested files as they come.  This would allow us to serve the files to StageWebView from their in-app locations, without copying.  We do this in a desktop air app and it works very nicely.  But, that approach uses ServerSocket, which I discover is not supported on mobile.  Is there an alternative way to do this?

Finally, StageWebView does not work well in the Flash Builder iOS simulator, making debugging difficult.  Is it best to just go and get FB 4.7, which (should) allow me to use it with XCode's iOS simulator?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems I CAN directly address the in-app content, I just have to construct a file:// URL for it:

```
var src:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("myFolder/index.html");
var newPath:String = "file://" + src.nativePath;
webView.loadURL(newPath);
```

Comment: how did you ever make out with this?  I came across it while trying to experiment with using local HTML and jquery on the users device, I have it working great so far but did you ever run into problems with the temp directory ("Is this a bad idea? Will temporary files pile up in my device with no way to delete them?")?  or does android clean items out of the temp folder automatically as needed?

Answer (score 0):

It's been too long since I thought about this.  But as I recall I was able to use in app content without making copies, for iOS.  But I am reading today where this might not be possible on Android.

Comment: Fred, if you want to edit your answer either log in on your other account or edit this one...

Comment: If you need it your edit was: "@davidkomer - I am not using the in-app HTTP server to deliver MP4 files. Instead I am using (believe it or not) JWPlayer, and the MP4 files are on a server somewhere.emphasized text If I had to guess about the MP4s, it might be that your in-app HTTP server is not properly handling progressive downloading. I know mine is not."

Answer (score 0):

It seems that StageWebView, when used with iOS, works best with remote files.  So, I am using some Actionscript code that implements a simple HTTP server, serving up local files.  Then, I give StageWebView http urls that use localhost, and a port number.  Works swell.

Comment: Hey Fred - I am able to do this, but for video (mp4) it fails... any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

After Adobe updated the SDK - the @Jesse Crosen method does not work for android but only on iOS. 
To make it work on Android you have to copy the packaged file like this:

```
var htmlFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("html/index.html");  
var fileDest:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("html/index.html"); 
htmlFile.copyTo(fileDest, true);
webView.loadURL("file://" + htmlFile.nativePath);
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone looking for a current solution to this problem that's simpler than writing an HTTP server, [this](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/11/06/getting-the-file-uri-of-a-file-in-an-air-apps-install-directory/) is what worked for me (on iOS only):

```
webView.loadURL(new File(new File("app:/myFolder/index.html").nativePath).url);
```

But there is a caveat, which is that it seems you can't pass in a query string or hash at the end of the URL. Data can be passed to the HTML content by loading a `javascript:` URL once the main content is loaded.

There's a page with broader information covering iOS and Android [here](http://www.dlgsoftware.com/StageWebViewAndLocalFiles.php).

Comment: Your solution does not work on android (but works on Desktop AIR). It throws ArgumentError exception 2004

Comment: @DeyanVitanov I'm aware of that, which is why I added the caveat "on iOS only" above. Just because it's not a universal solution doesn't mean it's not useful for someone.